# how to get values from SimpleXml Object

Tags: php, simplexml

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
  [results] => 2 
  [total_results] => 2 
  [plans] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [plan] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [id] => 1014 [type] => paid [name] => Silver [amount] => 1000.00 [interval] => 30 [notification_url] => http://www.google.com [free_trial] => 0 [occurrences] => 1 [num_customers] => 0 [status] => active ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [id] => 1013 [type] => paid [name] => Gold [amount] => 500.00 [interval] => 30 [notification_url] => http://www.movebyu.com/ExpressEngine/index.php/?ACT=21 [free_trial] => 0 [occurrences] => 1 [num_customers] => 1 [status] => active ) ) ) 
),
```

How to get values of plans, amount from these, can any one help me?

Comment: Next to the suggested xpath the manual has some basic examples which are very helpful to understand how simplexml works. http://ie2.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples.php

Answer (score 0):

Via XPath

http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php